# Use VB.Net Deleting Access Attachment In Attachment Field

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'd like to be able to delete individual files that are stored as attachments in an Access Database through VB.Net

I've managed to get storing, opening and "downloading" from an Access Database to work effectively, but the last piece of the puzzle would be to allow my end-user to delete an individual file in the attachments field.

This seems to be much harder than the other options as I can only seem to find information on how to delete the entire database entry, not just a single attachment. It gets even more complicated if there are more than one attachments stored against the entry.

I am using the following code to check what happens when the `datagrid` is clicked:

```
 If e.ColumnIndex = ViewFileColum.Index Then
        'Get the file name and contents for the selected attachment.
        Dim gridRow = childgrid.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim tableRow = DirectCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
        Dim fileName = CStr(tableRow(FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME))
        Dim fileContents = GetFileContents(DirectCast(tableRow(FILE_DATA_COLUMN_NAME), Byte()))

        DisplayTempFile(fileName, fileContents)
    End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = DownloadFileColumn.Index Then
        'Get the file name and contents for the selected attachment.
        MoveFile = True
        Dim gridRow = childgrid.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim tableRow = DirectCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
        Dim fileName = CStr(tableRow(FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME))
        Dim fileContents = GetFileContents(DirectCast(tableRow(FILE_DATA_COLUMN_NAME), Byte()))

        DisplayTempFile(fileName, fileContents)
    End If
```

I want to add a third section that states if the `DeleteFileColumn` button is clicked then to remove that particular attachment from the database, but this doesn't seem possible.

When retrieving the information for the above two options, I use the following code:

```
Dim tempFolderPath = Path.GetTempPath()
Dim tempFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, fileName)

'If the specified file exists, add a number to the name to differentiate them.
If File.Exists(tempFilePath) Then
    Dim fileNumber = 1

    Do
        tempFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFolderPath,
                                    String.Format("{0} ({1}){2}",
                                                  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                                                  fileNumber,
                                                  Path.GetExtension(fileName)))
        fileNumber += 1
    Loop Until Not File.Exists(tempFilePath)
End If

'Save the file and open it.

'If "DOWNLOAD" button is clicked
If MoveFile = True Then
    File.WriteAllBytes(SaveLocation & "\" & Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) & Path.GetExtension(fileName), fileContents)
    MoveFile = False


    'If "OPEN" button is clicked
Else
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, fileContents)
    Dim attachmentProcess = Process.Start(tempFilePath)

    If attachmentProcess Is Nothing Then
        'Remember the file and try to delete it when this app closes.
        tempFilePaths.Add(tempFilePath)
    Else
        'Remember the file and try to delete it when the associated process exits.
        attachmentProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        AddHandler attachmentProcess.Exited, AddressOf attachmentProcess_Exited
        tempFilePathsByProcess.Add(attachmentProcess, tempFilePath)
    End If
End If
```

This code copies the information before opening it, so I don't ever actually deal with the file in the database directly. I've used adapted this code from another example I found online, but am having a hard time working out how to physically deal with the file on the database, or if its even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Access DAO `Recordset2` object for the attachments field, find the record corresponding to the specific attachment you want to delete, and then `Delete()` that record.

The following example will remove a document named "testDocument.pdf" from the attachments field for the record where `ID=1`:

```vb
' required COM reference:
'     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
' 
' Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
'
Dim dbe As New DBEngine
Dim db As Database = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
Dim rstMain As Recordset = db.OpenRecordset(
        "SELECT Attachments FROM AttachTest WHERE ID=1",
        RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
rstMain.Edit()
Dim rstAttach As Recordset2 = CType(rstMain.Fields("Attachments").Value, Recordset2)
Do Until rstAttach.EOF
    If rstAttach.Fields("FileName").Value.Equals("testDocument.pdf") Then
        rstAttach.Delete()
        Exit Do
    End If
    rstAttach.MoveNext()
Loop
rstAttach.Close()
rstMain.Update()
rstMain.Close()
db.Close()
```